# various Windows 8 Metro app development approaches

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am starting developing Windows 8 Metro apps. It seems that there are 3 different approaches available for creating one:

- C#/XAML
- C++/XAML
- JS/HTML5

Do these approaches have the same functionalities and power?
I mean that if one develops an app in one these three, is it possible to recreate it in any of the other two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a simple application can be built on any of these platforms. Their won't be much difference. C++ code is generally more faster, if speed is a matter for you got that way!
There are some tools like DatePicker and all which are available only in JS/HTML but NOT on XAML(Alternatives are available though).
So yes! there is a bit difference in the API's available for each of them.

Their is a question already on the site explaining difference between C# and C++.
I personally prefer C#/XAML because it is easy and comfortable.

You may refer to it here:

[What are the pros and cons of writing C#/XAML vs. C++/XAML WinRT applications in Windows8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031929/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-writing-c-xaml-vs-c-xaml-winrt-applications-in)

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write the basic engine with the C# language and the mainview with HTML5.

If you know web development technologies, you can develop a Windows Store app using HTML5, Cascading Style Sheets, Level 3 (CSS3), and JavaScript.

If you have developed .NET, Windows Presentation Foundation, or Microsoft Silverlight applications, you can develop a Windows Store app using XAML, with code-behind in C++, C#, or Visual Basic.

If you know DirectX, you can develop a DirectX Windows Store app using native C++ and HLSL to take full advantage of graphics hardware.