# Windows 8 XAML - C++ vs C# - User Experience

Tags: c#, c++, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm currently writing several Windows store XAML apps in C# (my favorite language).
I'm planning to do a lot of future windows 8 development, and I need to make some concrete decisions about how I go about it - specifically whether I chose C# or C++ as my main approach.
For me the main factors are this:

Developing in C++ :

- secure (ish) from reverse engineering
- better memory usage on low spec devices
- large amounts of open source code available for implementing a wide range of features
- greater amount of control by writing code that runs 'closer to the metal'

Developing in C# :

- access to the very rich .NET framework
- quick to write, test and re-write code

So far its an even match, so the decision will ultimately come down to the differences in the user experience when writing a fairly complex XAML apps in either language / technology.

My question is - does anyone have good experience writing XAML apps in both technologies, and is the user experience equally good in both, or are there subtle differences (e.g. would a C++ version of an app be smoother to scroll with a large amount of data in a GridView with a complex ItemTemplate etc..)

Does anyone have any concrete, experience-based answers to help me out?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Maybe start with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031929/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-writing-c-xaml-vs-c-xaml-winrt-applications-in

Comment: Use the one you're most comfortable with. By using the other you'll loose more than you can gain.

Comment: So far my experience after spending months profiling Windows 8 apps tells me that all optimizations required in the UI don't depend on the language, though it might be easier to implement them in C#.

Answer (score 3):

Use both - C# for all the GUI stuff, C++ for number crunching etc.

C++/CLI provides a nice way to Interop between the two. So you have the speed and ease of development of C#, but can access all the libraries and have performance benefits of C++ where you need it.

Comment: I always feel the best answer to a which is best question is always 'Yes' and here is why. and this question sums up those points nicely, +1